# JQuery http GET for getting records by foreign ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am pretty new to whole Javascript, JQuery, Ajax thing. Is there a way to write GET request from API controller in ASP .NET Core which will get not all data (in my case messages) but messages by specific Foreign Id, something like **Linq** 
`.Where(r => r.ContactId == contactId);`

I wrote this kind of function which gets `contactId` and must pass it into that filter

```
    function showMessagesHistory(contactid) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("api/Messages/",
            (data) => {
                $.each(data,
                    (key, val) => {
                        var name = "name";
                        var str = val.body;
                        // console.log(str);
                        $(`<p class="chat-message">${str}</p>`)
                            .appendTo($('#messageDiv'));
                    });
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: So you will use the `Where` expression when querying the data in your server code. Your api method will accept the `contactId` value as a parameter (`Get(int id)`) and your getJSON call has to send the id via querystring.Ex : `/api/messages/45`.

Comment: call your api using query string $.getJSON("api/Messages/" +contactid ,

Comment: Thanks it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you must have a service on the server which expects the following route:

`api/Messages/{contactid}`

Then, consider your `contactid` in client as a part of the route in request URL like:

```
function showMessagesHistory(contactid) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("api/Messages/" + contactid,
            (data) => {
                $.each(data,
                    (key, val) => {
                        $(`<p class="chat-message">${val.body}</p>`)
                            .appendTo($('#messageDiv'));
                    });
            });
    });
}
```